# SpringMVC initbinder - binding list items form Integer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-initbinders

I have a page that has a list of custom items i register a custom editor in the init binder of the controller to allow data binding. The list is passed form the view. The problem i am having is i am on a view that is bind to a different object.However the both objects have an attribute in common crimeRecNo.

I have created a binder function under when the data is passed from the view to the controller for the custom object list however i would like to create a binder that receives an Integer and returns a list. Under is an example of what i have thus far, however it isnt binding:

I need to know how to register a custom editor that accepts a Integer crimeRecNo and returns a list and bind it to the list.

**Binder Function**

This is just not binding

```
crimeRecNoBinderVictimList.registerCustomEditor(Integer.class, "crimeRecNo", new CustomCollectionEditor(List.class){
        protected Object convertElement(Object element) {


            List<Citizens> victimList = new ArrayList<Citizens>();

            String crimeRecNo = null

            if (element instanceof String) {
                crimeRecNo = (String) element;

            }
            logger.info("Inside CrimeRecNo Binder crimeRecNoBinderVictimList " + crimeRecNo);


            try {
                victimList = citizenManager.getListOfVictimsByCrimeRecNo(Integer.parseInt(crimeRecNo));
            } catch (Exception e) {

                logger.error("Error In crimeRecNoBinderVictimList "+e.getMessage());
            }

            return victimList;              
        }       

    });
```

**Error**

```
102348 [http-bio-8084-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate  - Converting String to [int] using property editor [com.crimetrack.web.CrimeController$2@4b9e3acd]
102348 [http-bio-8084-exec-10] INFO  com.crimetrack.web.CrimeController  - Inside CrimeRecNo Binder crimeRecNoBinderCriminalList null
102348 [http-bio-8084-exec-10] ERROR com.crimetrack.web.CrimeController  - null
102358 [http-bio-8084-exec-10] INFO  com.crimetrack.web.CrimeController  - Inside CrimeRecNo Binder crimeRecNoBinderCriminalList 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Good question,

I'm not sure, but this tutorial on Spring's `@InitBinder` may help:

http://howtoprogramwithjava.com/session35